# How to pass more than 3 arguments to getattr?

Tags: python, traceback

I am learning how to use python's `*args*` and `**kwargs` notations. I am trying to use getattr to pass a variable amount of arguments to a function within another file.

The following code will take a console input, then search what module contains the function put into the console, then execute the function, using arguments.

```
while True:
    print(">>>", end = " ")
    consoleInput = str(input())
    logging.info('Console input: {}'.format(consoleInput))
    commandList = consoleInput.split()
    command = commandList[0]
    print(commandList) # Debug print
    """Searches for command in imported modules, using the moduleDict dictionary,
    and the moduleCommands dictionary."""
    for key, value in moduleCommands.items():
        print(key, value)
        for commands in value:
            print(commands, value)
            if command == commands:
                args = commandList[0:]
                print(args) # Debug print
                print(getattr(moduleDict[key], command))
                func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command, *args)
                func()
                output = str(func)
    else:
        print("Command {} not found!".format(command))
        output = ("Command {} not found!".format(command))
    logging.info('Console output: {}'.format(output))
```

I try to use a command that takes arguments, such a custom ping command I have made. But, I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dorian/Desktop/DEBPSH/DEBPSH.py", line 56, in <module>
    func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command, *args)
TypeError: getattr expected at most 3 arguments, got 4
```

How can I pass more than 3 arguments to the `getattr` function?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't unpack the tuple (or whatever it is) with `*`?

Comment: It's not always going to have the same number of arguments, that's why I used `*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass the arguments to the function, you need to use those in the *call to that function*. `getattr()` knows nothing about the attribute you are retrieving and takes no call arguments.

Do this instead:

```
func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command)
output = func(*args)
```

The `getattr()` argument only takes the object, the attribute to retrieve from it, and an optional default value if the attribute is not there.

Note that you don't need to call `str()` on the function either; at best you maybe want to convert the *return value* of the function call to string.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you **asked**; you don't. getattr only ever takes two or three arguments. And passing three arguments does nothing like what you're trying to do:

```
getattr(object, name[, default])
```

Calling, say, `getattr(math, "sin")` is the same as writing `math.sin`. This retrieves the attribute named `sin` in the `math` module which happens to be a function. There's nothing special about using `getattr` to do this. If you write `math.sin(i)`, you're getting the attribute `sin` from the `math` module and immediately calling it. `getattr(math, "sin")(i)` is basically identical to `math.sin(i)`.

As that's how function calls work normally, you'd want the following code instead:

```
func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command)
func(*args[1:])
```

This gets the command function from your module, then calls it normally, as if you directly called the function in your module. This isn't the only error in that part of the code though. Next, you write this:

```
output = str(func)
```

This is also wrong. `func` isn't magically replaced by the return value of the function you called. If it worked that way, after you call `math.sin`, nobody could use `math.sin` ever again. A function stored in a variable is like any other function, so you would obviously retrieve its return value like any other function:

```
func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command)
output = func(*args[1:])
```

Besides that, that segment of code seems to have one last error. `commandList[0:]` does nothing. You're asking for a slice from the first element to.... the last element. All this does is copy the list. What you probably wanted in the first place was `commandList[1:]`, which would get you every argument except the command. Fixing that, you get:

```
args = commandList[1:]
func = getattr(moduleDict[key], command)
func(*args)
```